# Access image in folder structure in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, ejs

I am trying to place an object in my index.ejs page using:

```
<img src="../images/logowhite.png" alt="white logo">
```

below is my folder structure:
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ5U4.png)

when I try to open the webpage, the image does not show, a small icon is shown and the alt-text is shown.

Comment: Where is the main file you are working with? Is it in the root of the folder, or is it in a folder?

Comment: it is not in the root folder, it is in a folder called views

Answer (score 0):

You have to remover the dots at the starting of the src.

Like this

```html
<img src="/images/logowhite.png" alt="white logo">
```

If that doesn’t work try without the first slash as well, that should work

Answer (score 0):

- Open the image(which is not being shown) in new tab using right click, and find where the image URL mismatches.
- And open the actual image(which you want) in new tab.
  **And compare them**.

  1. Using "/" at first in "/images/pic.png" means "abc.com/images/pic.png" or "abc.github.io/images/pic.png".

2. Using nothing at first place, i.e.-"images/pic.png" means in the page with url: "abc.com/views/index.html" means avoiding the last portion that is "index.html", which sends page request like "abc.com/views/images/pic.png" or "abc.github.io/views/images/pic.png" in place of "abc.github.io/views/index.html".
3. And each dots before slash justify the directory in the url, is to be avoided, for example: Img url is  - "abc.com/images/pic.png" and Page url is : "abc.com/js/index.html"
   Then write the image url as "../images/pic.png".
    And for sub-domains where the Page url is : "abc.github.io/repo/js/index.html" and the image url is "abc.github.io/repo/images/pic.png"
   Then write the image url as "./images/pic.png".

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="./images/logowhite.png" alt="white logo">
```

Use the ./ to specify it's a folder starting from current directory.

**Edit** Actually this will not work, I noticed the index.ejs is in views. Can you post the code from the index.ejs file?

**Edit2** if you're running the project on node js or using webpack:

```
const img = require('../images/logowhite.png');
<img src={img} alt="white logo">
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use absolute path for the image in src attributes.
To do that :-
1.Go to file where you have placed your image.
2.Right click on that file you will see absolute path option.
3.click on that option
4.come to back to html and paste the path in src and try again reloading the page.